# Epson Workforce printer driver

Tags: epson

I have had some problems installing an Epson WF-7610 on a new computer running 16.04 I have downloaded the driver from the website above. When I go to the list of printers in 'add printer' I get WF-7525 (recommended). This doesn't work! I have another laptop which uses the same printer and this works fine. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug that affects epson printers drivers (and others that depend on LSB). You can either wait till Epson or Canonical provides a fix, or use LSB from a previous Ubuntu version.

Check https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lsb/+bug/1536353